# Trouble PXE booting Live Linux Distributions from Windows Server

Tags: linux, windows-server-2012-r2, pxe-boot

I have been tasked with the project of making Windows Server 2012 r2 PXE boot live Linux distributions using WDS and I'm having trouble. I have a Blade server acting as the WDS, a Sonicwall handling DHCP and acting as a firewall (I do not have access to the Sonicwall) and a lab full of computers to PXE boot. I've followed the instructions I could find from multiple sources online. I have used the necessary files from Syslinux 5.01 (pxelinux, vesamenu, and chain) and renamed them as suggested, I have created the NFS share folder as suggested and created a TFTP server as found in other guides to serve the filesystem.squashfs file when NFS failed to boot. I believe that the error is in my default file (below) but I have no idea what it would be. Neither option (NFS for Ubuntu or TFPT for Kali) boots successfully. NFS gives me an error about needing a path, yet the path points exactly where the guides say to, and the TFTP errors out with no live filesystem found, but filesystem.squashfs is the live filesystem.

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks!

Sources: [Combining PXELinux with WDS](https://thommck.wordpress.com/2011/09/09/deep-dive-combining-windows-deployment-services-pxelinux-for-the-ultimate-network-boot/)
         [How to PXE boot live Linux CD](http://www.howtogeek.com/162809/how-to-pxe-boot-an-ubuntu-image-from-windows-server-2008/)

```
DEFAULT      vesamenu.c32
```

PROMPT       0

MENU TITLE PXE Boot Menu (x64)
MENU INCLUDE pxelinux.cfg/graphics.conf
MENU AUTOBOOT Starting Local System in 8 seconds

## Option 1 - Exit PXE Linux & boot normally

LABEL bootlocal

```
  menu label ^Boot Normally
  menu default
  localboot 0
  timeout 80
  TOTALTIMEOUT 9000
```

## Option 2 - Run WDS

LABEL wds

```
 MENU LABEL ^Windows Deployment Services
 KERNEL pxeboot.0
```

LABEL kali

```
 MENU LABEL ^Kali 2.0
 # Load the correct kernel
 kernel /Linux/Kali/live/vmlinuz
 # Boot options
 append priority=low vga=normal boot=live initrd=/Linux/Kali/live/initrd.img fetch=tftp://192.168.2.138/Linux/Kali/live/filesystem.squashfs
```

LABEL ubuntu

```
 MENU LABEL ^Ubuntu
 # Load the correct kernel
 kernel /Linux/Ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz.efi
 # Boot options
 append root=/dev/nfs priority=low vga=normal boot=casper netboot=nfs initrd=/Linux/Ubuntu/casper/initrd.lz nfsroot=192.168.2.13/RemoteInstall/Boot/x64/Linux/Ubuntu/casper/
```

## Option 3 - Exit PXE Linux

LABEL Abort
    MENU LABEL E^xit
    KERNEL abortpxe.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long dead thread, but I did find the solution.
The system loaded correctly, however, there were no video drivers so it appeared as a completely blank screen and seemed to be hung. Simply launch a tty terminal (ctrl+f3) and load drivers, then swap back (ctrl+f1) and bingo! You're in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

append this
nfsroot=192.168.2.13/RemoteInstall/Boot/x64.......

to this
nfsroot=192.168.2.13:/RemoteInstall/Boot/x64.............
Note the full colon after the IP address

Comment: I'm using the nfs root method for Kali as well and cannot get the filesystem.squashfs to load either. I have Ubuntu and Centos deploying after some work 
LABEL Linux  
MENU LABEL Deploy Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop Linux x64
Kernel Linux/ubuntu/Ubuntu-16-04-Desktop-x64/linux
append initrd=/Linux/Ubuntu/Ubuntu-16-04-Desktop-x64/casper/initrd.lz ramdisk_size=65536 root=/dev/nfs boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.3.1:/Linux-Distributions/ubuntu/Ubuntu-16-04-Desktop-x64